Get the name of the current python distribution (name field in pyproject.toml)
I am getting the version of my package using this code:
import importlib.metadata
importlib.metadata.version("mypackage")

As documented in this question
I would like to avoid hardcoding "mypackage" in this code and instead retrieve the package name from somewhere.  How can I do that?
Other info - I am using poetry to manage dependencies.  The package name is in my pyproject.toml file.
Option #1
Parse the __name__ variable.  Something like this probably works: __name__.split(".")[0]
This seems like a bad idea.
Option 2 - Parse the pyproject.toml file and grab the name from there.

See Single-sourcing the package version and Issue#273.
